# How do I change orientation of text in a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I have created type in a path in Illustrator, but the text is facing to the right - I would like to see it so it is readable at the top. Would appreciate any tips. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I mean I want the text to face in toward the circle instead of right-facing. Thx@

Comment: Hi Bess, welcome to GDSE.  I'm having difficulty visualising your problem. Any chance you could add a screen capture of the problem you are having? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i'm having a hard time picturing your issue, but maybe what you're looking for is the "Type on a Path" options. from the "Type" dropdown at the top, go to

Type on a Path > Type on a Path Options...

[image: Type on a Path Options]

make sure that "Preview" is checked (mine was unchecked by default), and try adjusting the settings to see if you get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>A</kbd> and zoom in on your text
- See those thin lines I've marked in red below. Drag them around and see what happens. Undo, redo, until you understand whats going on.

[image]